# Getting problems installation the Magento 1.9

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to install the newest version of Magento 1.9.1.0 localhost it is working fine but in the dev server I having this error? Has anyone know about it? Any idea how to solve it?

```
Notice: include(): 1. h->opened_path=[/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Locale.php]  h->filename=[Mage/Core/Model/Locale.php]
  in /lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94

#0 /lib/Varien/Autoload.php(94): mageCoreErrorHandler(8, 'include(): 1. h...', '/var/www/vhosts...', 94, Array)
#1 /lib/Varien/Autoload.php(94): Varien_Autoload::autoload()
#2 [internal function]: Varien_Autoload->autoload('Mage_Core_Model...')
#3 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(367): spl_autoload_call('Mage_Core_Model...')
#4 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(288): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initEnvironment()
#5 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(337): Mage_Core_Model_App->baseInit(Array)
#6 /app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 /index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#8 {main}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is with the APC
to solve it please follow below instructions.

Add to /var/www/yoursite.com/.htaccess :

- php_flag apc.cache_by_default Off
- php_flag apc.enabled Off

---

Then check to see if error comes again or not.

Hope it will works!!